# Как вставить текст в поле ввода на сайте в WebView?

Tags: java, android, webview

Есть WebView `webView`. Есть страница сайта.  В ней есть поле ввода текста:

```
<input class="" id="author" name="author" placeholder="Имя:*" type="text" value="" size="30" aria-required="true" style="border: 1px solid rgb(225, 225, 225);">
```

Как вставить в это поле нужный мне текст?

Answer (score 1):

Например, добавить в input атрибут value="my_value" перед тем, как кормить страницу в WebView

Answer (score 0):

если вы используете модель, то заполнить у нее нужное поле.

Answer (score 0):

Например так:
    author.value = 'blabla'